# Autostart on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have been looking for a few weeks now on how to make a .py file start on startup.
I have had no luck on any of the methods working, does anyone have any ideas.
The file is reasonably small and will need GPIO input from a PIR movement sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you using Raspbian you can simply add your script to the /etc/rc.local file see the snippet below:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# Your Py Script here:
/opt/myscript.py

exit 0
```

Comment: If [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is in fact supported, there's no need for this intermediary: `#!/usr/bin/env python` on the 1st line of the script should do the trick.

Comment: I needed to make a script that ran my python script. The python script needed to be made executable and then I used rc.local to call the script that ran my python script.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah we'll really need to know what OS you're using to be sure but assuming Raspbian the 2nd method on this link is the proper way to do it:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

> If you are looking for a solution that works on bootup to the console,
>   take a look at this link. Basic rundown:
>
> Create a file for your startup script and write your script in the
>   file:
>
> ```
> $ sudo nano /etc/init.d/superscript Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter
> ```
>
> Make the script executable:
>
> ```
> $ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/superscript Register script to be run at
> ```
>
> startup:
>
> ```
> $ sudo update-rc.d superscript defaults
> ```

Comment: I get errors about about missing LSB Tags and overides. 3 of these warnings, 2 in relation to supersript and mathkernel. e.g. insserv: warning: script 'K01superscript.py' missing LSB tags and overides.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script runs fine from the command line first.

Also, if you are dealing with the GPIO pins, make sure you are running your script with the proper permissions.  I know when I access the GPIO pins on my pi, I need to use root/sudo to access them.